# Download Games for non-Ultimate Windows machines

Tags: windows-7

I have Windows 7 Professional installed on my machine, but I'd like to play the games that come with Windows 7 Ultimate edition.

Is there a place to download those games?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All editions of Windows 7 come with the same games.

Maybe this will help you understand, and find your games.

1. Click the **Start** button, click **Control Panel**, click **Programs**,
   and then under **Programs and Features**, click **Turn Windows features on or
   off.**
2. Select the **Games** check box, and then click **OK**.

Refer the below link for details:

*Where are my games?*
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Where-are-my-games

Comment: Windows 7 Professional does not come with games like solitaire, spider, mine sweeper etc etc

Comment: @user22105 check the information and instructions I've added